# DataFrame cleaning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have an excel spreadsheet which, when imported looks similar to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
datetime(2021, 8, 1, 00, 00, 00): [120, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 300],
datetime(2021, 9, 1, 00, 00, 00): [np.nan, np.nan, 50, np.nan, np.nan],
datetime(2021, 10, 1, 00, 00, 00): [np.nan, 40, np.nan, 100, np.nan],
datetime(2021, 11, 1, 00, 00, 00): [80, np.nan, 50, np.nan, np.nan],
datetime(2021, 12, 1, 00, 00, 00): [np.nan, 20, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

| 2021-08-01 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-10-01 | 2021-11-01 | 2021-12-01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | NaN | NaN | 80 | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | 40 | NaN | 20 |
| NaN | 50 | NaN | 50 | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | 100 | NaN | NaN |
| 300 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

I'm looking (via python) to transform it into something like this:

```
shouldbe = pd.DataFrame({
"PayDate1": 
[datetime(2021,8,1), datetime(2021,10,1), datetime(2021,9,1), datetime(2021,10,1), datetime(2021,8,1)],
"Amount1": [120, 40, 50, 100, 300],
"PayDate2":
[datetime(2021,11,1), datetime(2021,12,1), datetime(2021,11,1), '', ''],
"Amount2": [80, 20, 50, np.nan, np.nan]}))
```

| PayDate1 | Amount1 | PayDate2 | Amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-01 | 120 | 2021-11-01 | 80 |
| 2021-10-01 | 40 | 2021-12-01 | 20 |
| 2021-09-01 | 50 | 2021-11-01 | 50 |
| 2021-10-01 | 100 | NaT | NaN |
| 2021-08-01 | 300 | NaT | NaN |

I'm looking for some examples of how to achieve this kind of transformation, thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: look at pandas.DataFrame.pivot, or get a list of the dates and build the data up manually

Comment: @2e0byo. The use of the pivot is not as obvious as it seems. There is a long way before to get the final dataframe. If you want to check my answer :)

Comment: @Corralien there is indeed; nice answer.  I didn't have time to figure it out, though looking at your answer I would just loop through and cope with the execution time rather than fight with pandas.  Very nice though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `melt`, `groupby` and `pivot` to get the expected dataframe:

1. Reshape your dataframe with `melt`:

```
out = df.reset_index() \
        .melt(id_vars='index', var_name='PayDate', value_name='Amount') \
        .dropna()
print(out)

# Output
    index    PayDate  Amount
0       0 2021-08-01   120.0  # <- index 0, 1st occurrence
4       4 2021-08-01   300.0  # <- index 4, 1st occurrence
7       2 2021-09-01    50.0  # <- index 2, 1st occurrence
11      1 2021-10-01    40.0  # <- index 1, 1st occurrence
13      3 2021-10-01   100.0  # <- index 3, 1st occurrence
15      0 2021-11-01    80.0  # <- index 0, 2nd occurrence
17      2 2021-11-01    50.0  # <- index 2, 2nd occurrence
21      1 2021-12-01    20.0  # <- index 1, 2nd occurrence
```

2. Group by `index` and apply `cumcount` to create index of new columns ('1' & '2' as string for future concatenation):

```
out['col'] = out.groupby('index').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
print(out)

# Output:
    index    PayDate  Amount  col
0       0 2021-08-01   120.0    1
4       4 2021-08-01   300.0    1
7       2 2021-09-01    50.0    1
11      1 2021-10-01    40.0    1
13      3 2021-10-01   100.0    1
15      0 2021-11-01    80.0    2
17      2 2021-11-01    50.0    2
21      1 2021-12-01    20.0    2
```

3. Pivot the dataframe

```
out = out.pivot(index='index', columns='col', values=['PayDate', 'Amount'])
print(out)

# Output
         PayDate            Amount      
col            1          2      1     2
index                                   
0     2021-08-01 2021-11-01  120.0  80.0
1     2021-10-01 2021-12-01   40.0  20.0
2     2021-09-01 2021-11-01   50.0  50.0
3     2021-10-01        NaT  100.0   NaN
4     2021-08-01        NaT  300.0   NaN
```

4. Get the final dataframe

```
cols = out.columns.get_level_values(1).argsort()
out.columns = out.columns.to_flat_index().map(''.join)
out.index.name = None

out = out[out.columns[cols]]
print(out)
    PayDate1 Amount1   PayDate2 Amount2
0 2021-08-01   120.0 2021-11-01    80.0
1 2021-10-01    40.0 2021-12-01    20.0
2 2021-09-01    50.0 2021-11-01    50.0
3 2021-10-01   100.0        NaT     NaN
4 2021-08-01   300.0        NaT     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for this insight, there's quite a few functions i've not seen before (.get_level_values, .argsort, .to_flat_index and cumcount). Also good to see the use of melt with the pivot feature too.

Answer (score 1):

Purely for completeness, here's the non-pandas way of doing it:

```py
import math
df = pd.DataFrame({
datetime(2021, 8, 1, 00, 00, 00): [120, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 300],
datetime(2021, 9, 1, 00, 00, 00): [np.nan, np.nan, 50, np.nan, np.nan],
datetime(2021, 10, 1, 00, 00, 00): [np.nan, 40, np.nan, 100, np.nan],
datetime(2021, 11, 1, 00, 00, 00): [80, np.nan, 50, np.nan, np.nan],
datetime(2021, 12, 1, 00, 00, 00): [np.nan, 20, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

dates = df.columns
out = {k: [] for k in dates}

for row in df.iterrows():
    for i, val in enumerate(row[1]):
        d = dates[i]
        if not math.isnan(val):
            out[d].append(val)

print(out)
```

This is not pandasy (indeed the final output here is not even a pandas dataframe, although it's trivial to transform it back into one), but I claim it's a good deal easier to read and thus More Pythonic (TM).  More to the point it *might* suit some use-cases better.

Comment: Thank you for this, this is a great way to iterate through the rows, extremely useful.